# Is there any graphic effects library compatible with MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, 2d

Is there any graphic effects library compatible with MonoTouch? I can't find any library, not even one able to do a simple sharpen or a "non fake" motion blur. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MonoTouch is build upon Mono which again is C#, so I think you should be able to search for tutorials for C#/.NET or Mono and see if there arent anything.

I havent searched myself, but is going to, as I am testing MonoTouch and iOS now too.